# Write to MemoryStream from ConnectStream asynchronously

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am writting a mp3 player which streams songs from Internet. The problem is that I can't use Seek() method in ConnectStream.
I thinking maybe it's possible to copy ConnectStream to MemoryStream asynchronously during streaming and use MemoryStream's Seek() method.
Does anyone has idea is it possible? Or maybe someone knows other way how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to allow the user to seek back and forth through the song, you are probably on the right track.  Allocate a MemoryStream, and use the [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) method (assuming that you are on .NET 4), as follows:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
myConnectStream.CopyTo(ms);
```

If you want to download and seek at the same time (like a youtube video for instance), you need to use slightly more complex techniques.  Rather than describe them in detail, I'll just refer you to the source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337900.aspx

Comment: As I understand than I call CopyTo() method it will copy only data which was downloaded at that moment. My idea is to seek through all currently downloaded data.

Comment: CopyTo will copy the stream until the stream's EOF, which for a network stream will be the end of the download.  When CopyTo reaches the end of what has been currently downloaded, it will block until more bytes are downloaded.  When the download stream is closed (because the whole file was downloaded or the connection is interrupted), the CopyTo call will finish.

Comment: That's better than nothing, but wanted that this copy action start working during downloading e.g after 1sec i downloaded half of song so at that moment user must have ability to seek  in that interval in song.

Comment: So, this means listener have wait till all data is downloaded to seek to a location. Good that it is not asked for video

Comment: Edited, added a link to an article explaining how to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost working, exept that every time new data is being 'copied' to memory stream, Position property's value is set to stream's length property's value. In this case when try to read from stream I do not get any data because 'cursor' reached end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with [System.IO.MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx). You are then buffering some of the stream in the local memory. Consider using [System.IO.BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is what he is after.  I think he wants the ability to buffer the whole MP3 in memory and allow the listener to seek back and forth through it, which the BufferedStream won't provide.